# jQuery REG EXP Conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a regular expression that I need to make conditional. What I'm doing is looking for a word or phrase and replacing wrapping it in a span. However, if I have a form element such as a checkbox input where the value of the input also contains the word or phrase, it attempts to add the span inside the value. Obviously breaking things. I need to conditionally only replace the words that are not inside of an input value.

Sample Code as it currently is:

```
 variable = htmlVar.replace( new RegExp( '(\\b' + worphrase + "\\b)", 'gi' ), '<span class="tooltip" id="' + i + '"> ' + worphrase + ' </span>' );
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The mixing of single and double quote characters is a little disconcerting...  Perhaps your regex should look more like `new RegExp('(<span[^>]*>)' + worphrase + '(</span>)', 'gi')`

Comment: I just realized that the way I wrote the question it cut out some of the words as html code. I'm trying to wrap the word or phrase in a span. Just not when it's inside of an input value.

Comment: Alright, then I would suggest using something like `new RegExp('(>[^>]*)' + worphrase + '([^<]*<)', 'gi')` and keeping the captured characters in the replacement.  This regex looks for the `worphrase` value in between a `>` and `<` which are characters that should never occur inside a tag like an `<input>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so as to have an answer to the question (rather than just comments):

In order to exclude the chosen value in the variable `worphrase` from being found within a tag `value` property (such as `<input value="worphrase">`), the following regexp searches for the pattern of a `>` character followed by non `<>` characters and the content of `worphrase` followed by (eventually) a `<` character:

```
new RegExp('(>[^<>]*)' + worphrase + '([^<>]*<)', 'gi')
```

Note that this updates the commented regexp to exclude both `<>` characters on each side of the given `worphrase` variable content.